# How can I have multiple handlers in same ProcessRequest method?

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, rest

I am calling a REST service from ajax, I have the following example call

myipaddress/RestWebService/employee?id=1",

The c# service code is shown below. My handler as above is "employee", I wish to add more handlers and was wondering can I do this from the same ProcessRequest method, I would like to parse out the handler and then direct the request with paramaters as required,

so I would like to have a call like

myipaddress/RestWebService/company?id=1",

Many Thanks

```
void IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {                
        string url = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Url);
        connString = @"";
        dal = new DAL.DAL(connString);
        errHandler = new ErrorHandler.ErrorHandler();

        //Handling CRUD
        switch (context.Request.HttpMethod)
        {
            case "GET":
                //Perform READ Operation                   
                READ(context);
                break;
            case "POST":
                //Perform CREATE Operation
                CREATE(context);
                break;
            case "PUT":
               //Perform UPDATE Operation
                UPDATE(context);
                break;
            case "DELETE":
                //Perform DELETE Operation
                DELETE(context);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errHandler.ErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
        context.Response.Write(errHandler.ErrorMessage);                
    }
}


/// <param name="context"></param>
private void READ( HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        int employeeCode = Convert.ToInt16(context.Request["id"]);

        //HTTP Request Type - GET"
        //Performing Operation - READ"
        //Data sent via query string
        //POST - Data sent as name value pair and resides in the <form section> of the browser
        emp = dal.GetEmployee(employeeCode);
        if (emp==null)               
            context.Response.Write(employeeCode + "No Employee Found");

        string serializedEmployee = Serialize(emp);

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

        //string serializedEmployee = JsonSerialize(emp);
        //context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
        WriteResponse(serializedEmployee);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteResponse("Error in READ");
        errHandler.ErrorMessage = dal.GetException();
        errHandler.ErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();                
    }            
}
```

Comment: for basic rest calls, you do not have to provide HttpHandlers, instead you can have API controller in ASP.Net MVC4 and then use `Redirect` in that controller.

Comment: Hi, I implemented a MVC api, works like a treat. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the implementaiton in C# but generally in java REST frameworks you can have varying value of path params, processed by a method. Here is the rest convention for it

```
myipaddress/RestWebService/{entity}?id=1
This at run time can cater to both type of request

myipaddress/RestWebService/employee?id=1
myipaddress/RestWebService/company?id=1
```

I hope your c# framework should be providing this feature as it is a REST convention.